# Should I use multiple query or functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table like:

```
id  name  fullname            parent_id
--  ----  -----------------   ---------
1   cat1  cat0 > cat1         null
2   cat2  cat0 > cat1 > cat2  null
3   cat3  cat1 > cat3         null
```

I want to get id of parent category and store into parent_id using sql query.

For example: In row 3, 'cat1' is the parent category of 'cat3', I want to get id of the parent category and store into `parent_id` field.

I splited out the parent cat name using

```
 select id,name,
      substring_index(
                      substring_index(fullname, '>', -2),'>',1)
      as parent from categories
```

From where I can name of parent category.

Expecting output like.

```
id  name  fullname            parent_id
--  ----  -----------------   ---------
1   cat1  cat0 > cat1         null
2   cat2  cat0 > cat1 > cat2  1
3   cat3  cat1 > cat3         1
```

Comment: do not seems a good idea use `fullname` in this form `cat3 > cat0`

Comment: I want to id of parent category and store into the field parent_id @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Use the parent name to join with the same table.

Comment: I know but database table already exists, I want to modify @mcNets

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I am far away from solution. please read my questions.

Comment: I did not get you. Did you read my problem? @PaulSpiegel

Comment: ok, now can you explain why the parent_id is 1?

Comment: fullname showing the tree of categories. so if you look row 3 then you will notice that `cat1` is the parent category of `cat3` and id of `cat1` is 1(from row 1) @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @RuhulAmin . . . You need to fix `fullname` for `cat3`.  It should be `'cat0 > cat1 > cat3'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, not really, depth is not always same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parent with a simple join:

```
select c.*, cp.id as parentid
from categories c join
     categories cp
     on c.fullname = concat(cp.fullname, ' > ', c.name);
```

You can turn this directly into an `update`:

```
update categories c join
       categories cp
       on c.fullname = concat(cp.fullname, ' > ', c.name)
    set c.parentid = cp.id;
```

Comment: can you explain a litle bit how that work? I try creating a fiddle and only return one row http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fe876/2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . With the correct data, it works:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb1f67/1.

Comment: Ok, that make more sense, still dont know how you see it.